# How to set queue name for Pig on Tez?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn, tez

How do I set a queue name from a command line when running Pig on TEZ?

I would like to run a Pig script from the command line such as:

```
pig -useHCatalog -p INPUT=input_dir \
                                 -p 'OUT_FILE=out_file \
                                 -p UDF_PATH=udf.py \
                                 -f ./script_name.pig \
                                 -Dmapred.job.queue.name=my_queue_name \
                                 -x tez;
```

I tried the following settings:

```
-tez.job.queue.name=my_queue_name
-q mapreduce.job.queuename=my_queue_name
-Dmapred.job.queue.name=my_queue_name
-q my_queue_name
```

However, my job is not running in the queue I specified.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is [`tez.queue.name`](https://tez.apache.org/releases/0.8.2/tez-api-javadocs/configs/TezConfiguration.html).

```
<property>
    <name>tez.queue.name</name>
    <value>myqueue</value>
</property>
```

So try

```
-tez.queue.name=my_queue_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In my version of pig (0.16.0.2.5.3.0-37) I could not set this parameter in the command line.

Instead adding

> SET tez.queue.name 'my_queue';

to the beginning of the PIG script did work.